# angularjs ng-options with formate date delete duplicates

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html

I made a filter for the field DataIscr on this json :

```
   [
        {
            "IdPers": "1067",
            "CognNome": "JANE SMITH",
            "Sex": "F",
            "DataIscr": "1949-12-29T00:00:00+01:00"     
        },
        {
            "IdPers": "1093",
            "CognNome": "JOHN SMITH",
            "Sex": "M",
            "DataIscr": "1969-12-02T00:00:00+01:00"             
        },
         {
            "IdPers": "1093",
            "CognNome": "JANE SMITH",
            "Sex": "F",
            "DataIscr": "1969-06-17T00:00:00+01:00"      
        }

        ]
```

and I used the format date: 'yyyy' to display only the year:

```
 <label for="DataIscr">DataIscr:</label>
 <select style="width:200px" data-ng-options="Person.DataIscr as Person.DataIscr|date:'yyyy' for Person in OutAnagrafica" id="DataIscr" data-ng-model="filter.DataIscr" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
```

plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/ED1v7czBosNSpCYxKW7n?p=preview

How can I delete the duplicates?? I want to filter object with the same year and the filter 'unique' from angular Ui doesn't work. How can I do??

Comment: Sidos what do you mean by duplicates ? based on name or year ?

Comment: Oh sorry, based on year! If you see my plunker there are two 1969

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sidos Check this out , i used 'angular.filter' modules unique filter .

```
<select style="width:200px" data-ng-options="Person for Person in OutAnagrafica| removeDuplicates      " id="DataIscr" data-ng-model="filter.DataIscr" class="form-control input-sm"></select>


App.filter('removeDuplicates', function ($filter) {
  return function (input) {
      var dates=[];
      angular.forEach(input,function(item,index)
      {
        dates.push($filter('date')(item.DataIscr,'yyyy')); 
      })
      console.log(dates);

      return $filter('unique')(dates);

  };
```

});

http://embed.plnkr.co/slrtdv/preview

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your comment, I changed my answer.

You can define a new `$scope.filtered` array and upon ajax success do:

```
$http.get('OutAnagrafica.json')
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.OutAnagrafica = data;

            $scope.OutAnagrafica.forEach(function(item) {

                 if (yearUnique($scope.filtered, item)) {

                   $scope.filtered.push(item);
                 } 
            });

        });
```

And you have the function `yearUnique`:

```
function yearUnique(arr, item) {

        var year = item.DataIscr.substring(0, 4); 
        var res = true;
        if (arr.forEach(function(i) {


          if (i.DataIscr.indexOf(year) > -1) {
            console.log('false');
               res = false;
          } 
        }));

        return res;
    }
```

And on the HTML:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="Person in filtered">  
           ...
</tr>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NJSUzgWaJh2OzW1kdwWA?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for your answer but I'm trying to delete duplicates based on year but unique from ui.utils doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the angular ui filter, write your own custom filter for filtering the date values. since the UI filter check for the whole value, it does not support the format the values for duplicate removal. below is the fiddle link for your scenario.

JS

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('OutAnCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.OutAnagrafica = [{
        "IdPers": "1067",
            "CognNome": "JANE SMITH",
            "Sex": "F",
            "DataIscr": "1949-12-29T00:00:00+01:00"


    }, {
        "IdPers": "1093",
            "CognNome": "JOHN SMITH",
            "Sex": "M",
            "DataIscr": "1969-12-02T00:00:00+01:00"


    }, {
        "IdPers": "1093",
            "CognNome": "JANE SMITH",
            "Sex": "F",
            "DataIscr": "1969-06-17T00:00:00+01:00"


    }];

    });
    app.filter('customDateUnique', function ($filter) {
        return function (arr, field) {
            return _.uniq(arr, function (a) {
                return $filter('date')(a.DataIscr, 'yyyy');
            });
        };

});
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div data-ng-controller="OutAnCtrl">
            <label for="DataIscr">DataIscr:</label>
            <select style="width:200px" data-ng-options="Person.DataIscr as Person.DataIscr|date:'yyyy' for Person in OutAnagrafica | customDateUnique" id="DataIscr" data-ng-model="filter.DataIscr" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1tw3zg9s/1/